# Overriding current CSS to add some padding

Tags: html, css, overriding

In the following code there is a label that is inheriting from the `rebrandWidgetheader` style class:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="rebrandWidgetHeader" ID="lblHeader">
```

I need to add some padding to the text so that I can position the label in the middle of the table.

I was thinking about adding a new class but I don't know what is inside the `rebrandWidgetHeader` class.

How do I override this class so that it can be added new padding but keeping all the old attributes?

Side note: I have already looked at the class through Internet Explorer developer tools,  but had no luck.

Comment: create your overrided class with what you need with "!important" it simply overrides the existing default style (ex:padding:10px !important)

Comment: first write this class in end of css fine `.rebrandWidgetheader {paddind:10px}` it will do if not than apply important `.rebrandWidgetheader {paddind:10px !important}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **!important** to the class style, to override the existing style.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the children class method:

.class .class2{ css }
or direct without further inheritance
.clas > .class2 { css }

it would be easier if you put some css code